# Visual Studio Code intellisense hinting

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've started using Visual Studio Code on El Capitan for javascript development and am really enjoying it so far, especially the code hinting, but I am encountering some behavior that I don't understand and hope someone can explain.

I'm working on a Backbone project, and if I'm in an object literal and add a new method, I get a popup/code hint that I don't understand and have to hit 'escape' to get out of. It's quite annoying as it comes up frequently. The popup looks like a function signature but I don't understand why it's there. It looks like:

```
(newNode: Node, offset: number): void
```

Can someone explain what this means and how I can get rid of it?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is called [IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx). It gives you more information about the function you are about to call.

In your example: 1/2 (newNode: Node, offSet: number) void

**1/2** - This indicates that there are 2 overloads for the function you are trying to call (You can click on the arrow or use ARROW KEY UP / ARROW KEY DOWN to navigate through all overloads)

**newNode: Node** - newNode is the name of the first parameter, Node is the class expected

**offSet: number** - offSet is the name of the second parameter, number is the type expected

**void** - indicates the return type, in this case, no return.

IntelliSense is one of the strengths of Static Typed / Pre compiled language such as C# or Java. I'd argue that one of the great features of Visual Studio Code is, that it provides you IntelliSense (to an extend) to a language such as JavaScript. (Dynamic, compiled on runtime). Visual Studio Code achieves this by using TypeScript files such as .d.ts and JSDocs (I believe).

Regarding deactivating it... I looked through the settings.json file and found only 2 commands regarding IntelliSense:

```
// Always include all words from the current document. (default: false)
"javascript.suggest.alwaysAllWords": false,

// Complete functions with their parameter signature. (default: false)
"javascript.suggest.useCodeSnippetsOnMethodSuggest": false,
```

You are able to access this file on Code -> Preferences -> User Settings.
You can also see the file referenced on [Visual Studio Codes Homepage.](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace)

Both do not achieve what you are looking for. <strike>This makes me think that you are not able to deactivate it.</strike>(SEE EDIT) You could look for a typings folder and remove/[exclude](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics) it from your project.

EDIT: After further research, I believe I found the settings you are looking for: [Editing Evolved.](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved)

You want to set:

```
editor.quickSuggestions: false,
editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters: false
```

in the settings.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I got bitten by this myself, very annoying bug. You can disable it with the following setting:

```
"editor.parameterHints": false
```

this will of course disable all hints even the useful ones. To me that's an acceptable tradeoff.